# How to create value for chart with Splunk

Tags: splunk

I have extracted a field from a log and named it `elapsedTime`:

```
... | rex "milisecond([\\\]{1})([\"]):(?<elapsedTime>\d+),"
```

Now I need to create a timechart that shows side-by side number of events per day and number of events with `elapsedTime` > 10000.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your environment, it's hard to give an accurate command. However, this should get you what you need (possibly with minor modification):

```
| timechart count by {events} AS Events, eval(elapsedTime > 10000) AS Long Events span=1d
```

`{events}` would be replaced with the variable name you're using for your events. You can obviously rename the `Events` and `Long Events` column headers to whatever names you choose.

You can also change the `span` from one day to whatever time period you choose. I only included one day because you indicated you wanted to chart the number of events per day.

For information on the various arguments and options you can use, see Splunk's [timechart documentation page](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/6.6.3/SearchReference/Timechart).